# Getting user input into excel (Apache poi)

Tags: java, excel, apache

I'm trying to use apache to get my user's entered info into an excel spreadsheet so I can save their account information. How do I get their usernames and passwords into this document so that each username and password combo has their own row? Here's my code so far:

Creating the sheet:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;


public class Spreadsheet {

    public Spreadsheet() {
        Workbook AccountInfo = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet Information = AccountInfo.createSheet();

        Row titles = Information.createRow(0);

        Cell username = titles.createCell(0);
        username.setCellValue("Username");

        Cell password = titles.createCell(1);
        password.setCellValue("Password");

        try {
            FileOutputStream Accounts = new FileOutputStream("Account Information.xls");
            AccountInfo.write(Accounts);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the user input:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class CreateAccount extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    Workbook AccountInfo = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet Information = AccountInfo.createSheet();

    JLabel username = new JLabel("Enter your username");
    JTextField enterUsername = new JTextField(null, 15);
    JLabel password = new JLabel("Enter your password");
    JPasswordField enterPassword = new JPasswordField(null, 15);
    JLabel passwordConfirm = new JLabel("Confirm your password.");
    JPasswordField enterConfirmPassword = new JPasswordField(null, 15);
    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");

    String userName;
    double balance;
    String passString;

    public CreateAccount() {

        add(username);
        add(enterUsername);
        add(password);
        add(enterPassword);
        add(passwordConfirm);
        add(enterConfirmPassword);
        add(okButton);

        okButton.addActionListener(this);

        setTitle("New Bank Account Creation");
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(270, 250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        char[] pass = enterPassword.getPassword();
        passString = new String(pass);

        char[] passConfirm = enterConfirmPassword.getPassword();
        String passStringConfirm = new String(passConfirm);

        userName = enterUsername.getText();

        if (e.getSource() == okButton) {
            if(userName.isEmpty() || passString.isEmpty() || !passString.equals(passStringConfirm)) {

                    enterUsername.setText("");
                    enterPassword.setText("");
                    enterConfirmPassword.setText("");
                    Border redLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red);
                    enterUsername.setBorder(redLine);
                    enterPassword.setBorder(redLine);
                    enterConfirmPassword.setBorder(redLine);
                    }
            }if(!userName.isEmpty() && !passString.isEmpty() && passString.equals(passStringConfirm)){
                    addAccount(userName,passString);

                super.dispose();

            int response = 0;
            String firstDesposit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome " + userName + ". Enter your initial deposit.\n" + "If you wouldn't like to make an initial deposit, press CANCEL.");
            balance = Double.parseDouble(firstDesposit);
            if (response == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                new Menu();
                }
            }   
        }
    private void addAccount(String username, String password) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("Account Information.xls"));           
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file); 
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        int newRowIndex = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); //index of new row to create
        HSSFRow newRow = sheet.getRow(newRowIndex);

        HSSFCell usernameCell = newRow.createCell(0);
        usernameCell.setCellValue(username);
        HSSFCell passwordCell = newRow.createCell(1);
        passwordCell.setCellValue(password);
    }
}
```

Here is the class where I am trying to implements a confirmUsername() method.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;


public class ViewAccount extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    AccountSpreadsheet spreadsheet = new AccountSpreadsheet();
    JLabel userName = new JLabel("Username:");
    JTextField enterUserName = new JTextField(null,15);
    JLabel Password = new JLabel("Password:");
    JTextField enterPassword = new JTextField(null,15);
    JButton log = new JButton("Login");
    Account account;    

    public ViewAccount() {

        add(userName);
        add(enterUserName);
        add(Password);
        add(enterPassword);
        add(log);
        log.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 40));
        log.addActionListener(this);

        setTitle("Login");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300,150);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == log) {
            confirmUsername();
            }
        }
    public void confirmUsername() {
        AccountSpreadsheet Spreadsheet = new AccountSpreadsheet();
        CreateAccount Acct = new CreateAccount();
        String passString = Acct.passString;
        String userName = Acct.userName;


        for (Iterator<Row> rit = Spreadsheet.sheet.rowIterator(); rit.hasNext();) {
            Row row = rit.next();
            for (Iterator<Cell> cit = row.cellIterator(); cit.hasNext();) {
                Cell cell = cit.next();
                String name = cell.getStringCellValue();
                if(userName == name) {
                    cit.next();
                    if(passString == name){
                        System.out.println("Log success");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("ERROR");
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that calling the CreateAccount is going to just make another window from the CreateAccount constructor to pop up, but I was unsure how else to get the userName and passString into the method.

Comment: So the issue is that you're not sure how many rows have already been filled so you're not sure where to create the new one?

Comment: @yts I'm not sure how I can take the username and password a user enters and put them into the "Username" and "Password" columns of my created excel spreadsheet. I would like to get the usernames and passwords into this spreadsheet so that I can later allow the user to log in to make deposits and withdrawals.

Comment: I'm working on an answer, but are you sure you want to do this? A database is much more suited for this.

Comment: @yts My AP Computer science class assignment was unfortunately limited to using apache for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have for Spreadsheet shouldn't be run more than once. Doing so will delete whatever information you had stored. Here's a good spreadsheet class.

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.*;

public class AccountSpreadsheet {

    private XSSFSheet sheet;
    private final String filename = "Account Information.xlsx";

    public AccountSpreadsheet() {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            createSpreadsheet(); //file didn't exist yet
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void createSpreadsheet() {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
        XSSFCell username = row.createCell(0);
        username.setCellValue("Username");
        XSSFCell password = row.createCell(1);
        password.setCellValue("Password");
        save();
    }

    public void addAccount(String username, String password) {
        int newRowIndex = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        XSSFRow newRow = sheet.createRow(newRowIndex);

        XSSFCell usernameCell = newRow.createCell(0);
        usernameCell.setCellValue(username);
        XSSFCell passwordCell = newRow.createCell(1);
        passwordCell.setCellValue(password);
        save();
    }

    private void save() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            sheet.getWorkbook().write(outStream);
            outStream.close();
            sheet = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(filename))).getSheetAt(0); //POI bug requires this
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//    public boolean accountExists(String username){
//        //does account exist?
//    }
//
//    public boolean correctLogin(String username, String password) {
//        //correct username and password?
//    }
}
```

Have an instance of AccountSpreadsheet in your CreateAccount class and call addAccount(username, password) after validating them.

Comment: What would a method to validate a login look like? I tried used an iterator to go through the list until it hits the username entered (if it matches one entered) and then call cell.next() to see if the password was the one assigned to the username but couldn't get it functioning properly.

Comment: What's not working about it? Post a question with your code and issues you're having and give me the link here and I'll take a look. Can't guarantee as complete of an answer as I gave here but I'll try to point you in the right direction ;)

Comment: Added the ViewAccount class, the method is at the bottom!

Comment: I don't like what you did at all :( So many issues :/ I'm going to try to give you a skeleton to follow

Comment: Ok thanks. What I did was just a guess since I'm unsure how to apply all this (I understand the basics in programming but I'm still trying to improve a lot)

Comment: I don't understand why you're learning a 3rd party API (Apache POI) when you still have to learn the fundamentals of OOP in Java. There's nothing wrong with learning, everyone started as beginners (I'm not so advanced myself), but your class shouldn't make you use Swing and Apache POI before you have a stronger foundation.

Comment: My class is very poorly taught. I agree I still need lots of practice with fundamentals but unfortunately we are getting these projects thrown at us. Also, what do you recommend that I can do to improve my understand of OOP.

Comment: This is too much, I'm truly sorry. You should have an _instance variable_ for the AccountSpreadsheet class I made for you in both Frame classes. 1. Don't access the spreadsheet directly by doing spreadsheet.sheet. Have the methods in the AccountSpreadsheet class do the work. 2. When you loop through an iterator, use while(iter.hasNext()). 3. When you compare strings, use the string.equals(string) method, not the == operator. There's more, but I just can't help you with it right now :( Good luck and google is your best friend.